# How to fix theme for PyQt5 applications?

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt, gtk, themes, pyqt5

I've tried using PyQt5 from pip as well as apt (python3-pyqt5) on the same system. Both of these versions result in different themes (the images are below).

I've tried setting the environment variable `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` to "gtk" as well as "gtk+", but couldn't get the native look.

I'm curious about why this is happening. How can I force it to use QGtkStyle? Other native apps like Clementine, VLC, Zeal work with QGtkStyle theme and also blend as per gnome-shell theme.

Following some online instructions, I tried qt5-style-plugins, which doesn't have gtk theme.

Installed from pip (QFusionStyle):

[image: installed from pip]

Installed from apt (QGtkStyle):

[image: installed from apt]

Comment: Try setting DESKTOP_SESSION to gtk

Comment: Didn't work. QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME is the same "appmenu-qt5" in both cases, and DESKTOP_SESSION is "ubuntu"

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar. You say "both of these versions result in different themes" - but different to *what*? Is *either* of them what you were expecting? Or is there some other style you were expecting that you haven't told us about? Please show a screenshot of a "normal" Qt application (i.e. not a PyQt5 application) that has the style you are expecting.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar. The pip-installed PyQt5 will use a wheel, which has its own copy of Qt5. This means it won't have access to the usual plugins that your system Qt5 has. The style shown in the first screenshot is the default `fusion` widget-style.

Comment: @ekhumoro I wasn't expecting the fusion widget-style. I was expecting the second one, which is same as all other applications on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This is getting a little long for a comment so here are some things to try:

- Setting DESKTOP_SESSION (didn't help in your case)
- Print QApplication.style().metaObject().className(), see if it is the same for both runs. There may be other useful properties on the style object. Also
- Print QStyleFactory.keys(), the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE must be one of the printed values.
- Look at [Uniform look for Qt and GTK applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications)
- The --style option overrides QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE setting
- There could be a plugin style that gets activated in one of the installations

Comment: The result of style().metaObject().className() in first case is QFusionStyle, and for second is QGtkStyle. If I try any string through the "style" parameter, it leads to QWindowsStyle. How can I force QGtkStyle? I am looking for some way that makes changing gnome-shell theme effective on the application too. Clementine, VLC work that way. I'm looking for same way here. Help would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar. I already explained why you get the default `fusion` style with pip installs. You need to add the required style plugin to the copy of Qt5 installed by the wheel.

Comment: Moreover, using style as `gtk2` with pip version freezes the system. Looks like pyqt 5.7 dropped gtk theme support. The apt version is perhaps tweaked for this.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar. Why would you want to use a gtk2 style plugin if the rest of your system isn't using it? I thought you wanted everything to look the same? Presumably, ubuntu is mostly based on gtk3, which doesn't use style plugins (it's all CSS-based).

Comment: @ekhumoro Coz I tried `gtk3` and it looked horrible. The application looked like 2 times magnified. Giving style `gtk3`, it implements `QCleanlooksStyle`.

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar. Looks like you'll have to compile [qtstyleplugins](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/) for the pip-installed copy of Qt5 if you want the gtk2 plugin.